# in place quick sort has O(n) or O(logn) space complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This Wikipidea article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version suggests that O(logn) is the space time complexity for in place sort and http://futur3googl3r.blogspot.com/2008/08/google-interview-questions.html this interview site suggests it is O(n). I think the answer is O(n) but wanted to know if I am right.

Comment: Both of them *probably* describe the same algorithm (I didn't read into the details). O(n) *extra* space is **worst** case, and O(log n) *extra* space is on **average**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In both articles, the space complexity that they are referring to is of the **extra** space (not counting the space needed to store the original array). This **extra** space may come from the call stack, in addition to the common case where an extra array is declared. Each recursive call will create a stack frame on the call stack, which takes up space, and the number of stack frame is dependent on input size `n`, so it needs to be counted.

Let us use the Wikipedia article for reference, since the blog is quite inconsistent as pointed out by @Jim Mischel.

For in-place quick sort, modifying from the naive implementation will give `O(log n)` *extra* space **on average**, instead of the `O(n)` *extra* space (in all cases) in the naive implementation. The **worst case** complexity of *extra* space, as pointed out correctly by the blog<sup>1</sup>, is `O(n)`, when the algorithm encounters its worst case (a sorted list; there will be `n` recursive calls so the call stack will take up `O(n)` *extra* space).

<sup>1</sup>: (Thanks to @rici for pointing out) However, the blogger is only correct if we assume an implementation without the optimization as mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations). It is possible to improve the algorithm to use `O(log n)` **extra** space in worst case, by recursing on the smaller portion first and implementing a tail call for the longer portion. Since the smaller portion is always less than half of the input size, there will be at most `O(log n)` recursive calls. Assuming tail-call optimization is done, the longer portion will reuse the current stack frame without incurring extra spaces. If tail-call optimization is not done, we can always write an iterative implementation with explicit stack.

Comment: Worst case complexity is O(n) but H2CO3 gives O(logn) as worst case complexity without giving the reason.

Comment: The first paragraph of that blog is contradictory. It correctly points out that the worst case is O(log n) recursive calls, but then goes on to say that it can make O(n) nested recursive calls. Which one is it? And the second paragraph is so far out in left field that it's incomprehensible.

Comment: @JimMischel: The blog seems to be quite inconsistent about the worst case complexity extra space of in-place quick sort. Worst case is O(n), and average case is O(log n).

Comment: Writing quicksort to take worst-case O(log n) space is exercise 7-4 in my copy of Cormen &al, which is, imo, a better reference from some random blogger who clearly doesn't get the concept of tail-recursion.

Comment: @vkaul11: The key is that if you always recurse first on the shorter partition, then the number of *nested* recursive calls is `o(log n)` because the shorter partition is less than half the size of the total partition. Tail recursion is not a *nested* call, so the blogger is wrong (and I don't believe he's a googler, either).

Comment: @rici: "Tail recursion is not a nested call." I am not sure why analysis has to take into account the optimization done by compiler...

Comment: @rici: Anyway, I have modified the post so that it correctly addresses the solution with O(log n), instead of saying that it is plainly O(n) worst case.

Comment: @vkaul11: I have edited my post. The blogger is not aware of all the implementation optimization that can be done to improve the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You don't need any help from the compiler; you can rewrite the tail recursion as a loop all by yourself. No explicit stack is needed. However, note that Hoare's original quicksort algorithm did use an explicit stack, and he described it carefully to ensure the explicit stack could be preallocated with log2(n) slots.

Comment: @rici: (If it is you who downvoted, would you please check whether the post has mentioned the right thing and remove the downvote?)

Comment: @nhahtdh: Given what I just pointed out regarding the description by Hoare of quicksort, I'd be inclined to replace the word "naive" by "incorrect". It's not an optimization; it's part of the algorithm as originally written. However, I removed my downvote.

Comment: @rici: Well, the thing is space complexity is not taught in my university, and everything I know about space complexity is from reading Wikipedia article. They don't even mention anything about the implementation details that can improve the space complexity (they talk about in-place quick sort directly, but not the modification to decrease space complexity). Thanks for the discussion - it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> This interview suggests it's O(n)

No, it doesn't:

> Solution: Quicksort has a space complexity of O(logn), even in the worst case.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the algorithm. As the wikipedia article explains there are two implementations, you cna make the simple implementation with O(n) space and the better implementation which uses only O(logn) space

Comment: Read the complete solution "The version of quicksort with in-place partitioning uses only constant additional space before making any recursive call. However, if it has made O(logn) nested recursive calls, it needs to store a constant amount of information from each of them. Since the best case makes at most O(logn) nested recursive calls, it uses O(logn) space. The worst case makes O(n) nested recursive calls, and so needs O(n) space."
See in the link I posted http://futur3googl3r.blogspot.com/2008/08/google-interview-questions.html

Comment: @Techmonk The article also says "when implemented carefully" :)

Comment: H2CO3, you can at least explain why the worst case complexity is not O(n) but O(logn) instead of just saying it is so.